# Более быстрые аналоги Selenium для python для парсинга страниц, которые подгружаются с помощью javascript?

Tags: python, парсер

Мне нужно запарсить отдельные элементы конкретного сайта, но они грузятся с помощью javascript. Я пробовал selenium (chrome webdriver), но он слишком медленный. Какие существуют более быстрые аналоги?

Comment: Просто посмотрите, какие именно http-запросы делает браузер, и повторите такие же в питоне?

Comment: @andreymal а как можно это сделать (я новичок в программировании)?

Comment: @andreymal, если заглянуть на вкладку network (там, где показываются запросы get/post/option и пр.) то в запросах get там одни картинки -_-

Comment: А медленно это как? И еще, почему вы думаете, что дело в селениуме? Процесс то состоит из многих шагов: старт браузера, загрузка страницы, рендеринг, выполнение javascript-a, собственно парсинг.